# Paste text from clipboard to fill multiple form fields

Tags: javascript, forms, clipboard

I have a login form (username + password) on a site I don't have the power to control and I want to use some of the clipboard magic to fill it. On my website, I have a set of two buttons: one for copying the username and one for the password. But I have to click to copy and then paste twice to fill the login form. Ideally, I'd have one button which would do it all in a single action.

I wonder if there is a way to write username and password to the clipboard in a special way that will allow me to fill the form with a simple <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. Is it even possible or do I need to mess with browser extensions?

I tried separating the values with a newline and a tab but none of them worked.

Comment: There's no such thing, you'd need to mess with browser extensions.

Comment: Ok thanks. I guess it's finally a good time to check them out